# IOS 6 with ARC, How to prevent Table View to not ask for new Cells when they are not discarded

Tags: ios, uitableview

IOS 6, ARC, trying to see if there is a way to prevent a custom table view cell from being "dropped" from the table list even if the cell is off screen.  Yes, Yes, I know, should not be doing this but just experimenting now.

In cell for row at index path....

Tried with re-use identifier = nil.  Also, just tried creating the cell every time and then having the cell strong referenced with a local array.

The table will ask for cells that have been "off screen" even if the cell seems to not have been discarded.

Again, understood that this is strange way of doing this.

Any discussions on this?  Another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that it will always ask for cells that have been "off screen". If you keep strong references to the cells, you will have to release them yourself.

You could store the cells in an array or dictionary (indexed by row), and return the existing cell if it's in the list, otherwise create a new cell when iOS asks for one.

Comment: Yes, would have probably do a strong reference like your said and then find it again, etc.